# Has and belong to many Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I want to create a many to many relationship between two models, and I'd like to know step by step what to do. I'd like to have a explanation on HOW to do the migrations and HOW to ideally create the models. The way i'm trying to do right now is:

I create two models in the Ruby command line:

```
rails g model Location name:string
rails g model Datetime date:datetime
```

Now I have to open the recently created models and add:

```
//models/location.rb
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belong_to_many :datetimes
end

//models/datetime.rb
class Datetime< ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belong_to_many :locations
end
```

Now apparently I have to do a migration, but I don't understand what it is, and the I guess some sources for oldest versions really got me confused. Can someone please explain in details?

Obs: There are some similar questions **but** they do not answer my question because they don't explain in depth what to do.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: I've read that, but I still don't understand :/

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by ruby tutorial, we generate a new migration:

```
rails g migration CreateDatetimesAndLocations
```

Inside this migration i have:

```
class CreateDatetimesAndLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      create_table :locations_datetimes, id:false do |t|
        t.belongs_to :datetime, index: true
        t.belongs_to :location, index: true
      end
    end
end
```

This is done exactly like the ruby tutorial. Now I have this controller, that i'm testing on and it goes like that:

```
class WeatherController < ApplicationController
  def data
     @location = Location.new
     @location.name = "test"
     @datetime = Datetime.new
     @datetime.date = DateTime.new(2001,2,3)
     @location.datetimes << @datetime // **PROBLEM ON THIS LINE**
     @location.save

     @location = Location.new
     @location.name = "teste2"
     @location.locations << @location
     @locations = Location.all //(show locations in view)
  end
end
```

The problem I was having was because the locations_datetimes have to be datetimes_locations (in alphabetic order apparently).